# read keys from configuration file

Tags: c#

I have a configuration file which contains:

```
    <add key="x36_key1" value="D1"/>
    <add key="x36_key2" value="D2"/>
    <add key="x36_key3" value="D3"/>
    <add key="x36_key4" value="D4"/>
    <add key="x36_key5" value="D5"/>
```

Now I need those keys to be used here:

```
   case Keys.D1:
          //something happens here
        break;
   case Keys.D2:
          //something happens here
        break;
   case Keys.D3:
          //something happens here
        break;
   case Keys.D4:
          //something happens here
        break;
   case Keys.D5:
          //something happens here
        break;
```

The way I pull out the value from each key is like this:

```
string key1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["x36_key1"];
```

But as it is a string it can't be used as a key.

How can I make the code read the keys that where defined in the configuration file?

Answer (score 3):

You should parse string to enum `Keys` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
string key1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["x36_key1"];
Keys key;
if (Enum.TryParse<Keys>(key1, out key))
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case Keys.D1:
            //something happens here
            break;
        case Keys.D2:
            //something happens here
            break;
        case Keys.D3:
            //something happens here
            break;
        case Keys.D4:
            //something happens here
            break;
        case Keys.D5:
            //something happens here
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! and how about if I have more than one `string key1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["x36_key1"];` as in the app.config file I have more than 1 definition for each key?

Comment: You can extract method with switch statement and invoke this method with different parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Parse the string from the configuration into `Keys` enum using [Enum.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var keyFromConfiguration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["x36_key1"];

Keys key = (Keys) Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), keyFromConfiguration);

switch (key)
    {
        case Keys.D1:
            //something happens here
            break;
        case Keys.D2:
            //something happens here
            break;
        case Keys.D3:
            //something happens here
            break;
        case Keys.D4:
            //something happens here
            break;
        case Keys.D5:
            //something happens here
            break;
    }
```

Comment: If my code uses "switch (e.KeyCode)" how would it be? I say it because "key" will not get recognized once I use it in "case Keys.key"

Answer (score 0):

```
string key1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["x36_key1"];
Keys k1 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), key1);
```

Comment: If my code uses "switch (e.KeyCode)" how would it be? I say it because "key" won't get recognized once I use it in "case Keys.key:"